# Generate serial no. in List using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three models and one View model. The models are like:

```
public partial class SalesDetail
    {
        public long IID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> SalesId { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public int UoM { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> Disc { get; set; }

        public virtual General General { get; set; }
        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual Sale Sale { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Item
    {
               public Item()
        {
            this.SalesDetails = new HashSet<SalesDetail>();
        }

        public int IID { get; set; }
        public string Item1 { get; set; }
        public int UoM { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<SalesDetail> SalesDetails { get; set; }
    }



    public partial class General
        {
            public General()
            {
                this.Parties = new HashSet<Party>();
                this.Parties1 = new HashSet<Party>();
                this.SalesDetails = new HashSet<SalesDetail>();
            }

            public int IID { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string Desciption { get; set; }
            public byte Type { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a view model like:

```
public class SalelsDetailListViewModel
    {
        public int SerialNo { get; set; }
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public int UoM { get; set; }

        public string UnitName { get; set; }

        public int Qty { get; set; }

        public decimal? Disc { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to generate serial no. while executing the linq query as a list. Later this list will be displayed as a table with the serial no.
I have written the following query.

```
lstDetails = (from d in db.SalesDetails
                                  join i in db.Items on d.ItemId equals i.IID
                                  join u in db.Generals on d.UoM equals u.IID
                                  select new SalelsDetailListViewModel
                                                                       {
                                      SerialNo = ???,
                                      Id = d.IID,
                                      ItemId = i.IID,
                                      ItemName = i.Item1,
                                      UoM = u.IID,
                                      UnitName = u.Value,
                                      Qty = d.Qty,
                                      Disc = d.Disc
                                  }).ToList();
```

I can't understand how to increment the serial no inside the query with other items.
Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks

Partha

Comment: just before you declare `lstDetails` you can declare `int count = 0` and do `SerialNo = count++`
But how will you use that serial, if you generate it on the fly? To your client it is meaningless, if someone sees it in a view and sends it back, how are you going to match it to your data?

Comment: I have tried it but serial no is always 0.

Comment: I've tested my suggestion and it works. I have provided a number of alternatives in my answer below. Let me know if it's not working for you and we will figure out why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not simply iterate over the result and set the using a counter?
How many elements do you have? Are you concerned with performance?

**What difficulty are you facing?**

```
var counter = 0;
foreach (var x in lstDetails) x.SerialNo = counter++;
```

You could also do it in the original query, like below (using C# 7 ValueTuple)

```
var sample = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
var count = 0;
sample.Select(x => (x, count++)).ToList();
// result
// List<ValueTuple<string, int>>(3) { [(a, 1)], [(b, 2)], [(c, 3)] }
```

Or an anonymous type, [try with Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5oUYhi)

```
var sample = new [] { "a", "b", "c" };
var count = 0;
sample.Select(x => new { x, c = count++ }).ToList();
// result
// List<<>f__AnonymousType0#8<string, int>>(3) { \{ x = "a", c = 1 }, \{ x = "b", c = 2 }, \{ x = "c", c = 3 } }
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Here is an alternative solution that should work better

```
    var lstDetails = (from d in salesDetailsList
                      join i in itemList on d.ItemId equals i.IID
                      join u in generalList on d.UoM equals u.IID
                      select new
                      {
                          Id = d.IID,
                          ItemId = i.IID,
                          ItemName = i.Item1,
                          UoM = u.IID,
                          UnitName = u.Value,
                          Qty = d.Qty,
                          Disc = d.Disc
                      })
                      .Select((s, index) => new SalesDetailListViewModel()
                      {
                          SerialNo = index,
                          Id = s.Id,
                          ItemId = s.ItemId,
                          ItemName = s.ItemName,
                          UoM = s.UoM,
                          UnitName = s.UnitName,
                          Qty = s.Qty,
                          Disc = s.Disc
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I believe your answer is an implementation of my comment, and a subset of my answer, and also - this is the right way to do it. Any idea why my answer is downvoted? Thanks!

Comment: SerialNo = serialCount++ is not working. Getting compile time error 'An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator'. So I have changed it to SerialNo = serialCount+1. But the SerialNo is always 1.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? I tested it in LinqPad and it worked.

Comment: @ironstone13 Not sure. Maybe it didn't work for what they were doing? I rarely downvote other answers so it wasn't me.

Comment: @Partha I updated the answer. This might work better for what you're doing.

Comment: Hi Mat thanks for your effort. I am getting this error : "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebApp.Models.SalelsDetailListViewModel] Select[<>f__AnonymousType9`7,SalelsDetailListViewModel]"

Comment: @Partha Check the spelling.

Comment: Checked it. I think the issue is not with spelling.

Comment: @Partha It looks misspelled. SalelsDetailListViewModel should be SalesDetailListViewModel.

Comment: @MattLaCrosse, you got to the root of the problem, hence the upvote!